# HTML5 Video - Start video at certain time and play for x amount of time

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to create buttons that start my local video at a certain point in time and have it play for a certain duration. I've got it to play at a certain point but not sure how to let it play for only certain duration.

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<video id="myvideo" width="1000">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
    <div>
        <p>
            <button id="playme">Play/Pause Video</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="jump">Jump to 4 seconds</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="jump2">Jump to 11 seconds</button>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo'),
playbutton = document.getElementById('playme'),
jumplink = document.getElementById('jump'),
jumplink2 = document.getElementById('jump2');

jumplink.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 4;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);

jumplink2.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 11;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);

playbutton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (myvideo.paused) {
        myvideo.play();
    } else {
        myvideo.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned which browser you're using, but if it's Chrome, you may be experiencing a bug. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1018533 (Similar bugs have been filed and closed numerous times over the years, because it apparently only occurs with some videos.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to poll the video's `currentTime` property as it's playing, perhaps with something like this general code...

```
var button = document.getElementById('play')
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var startTime = 10;
var endTime = 20;

button.addEventListener('click', playVideo, !1);

function playVideo(e) {

    function checkTime() {
        if (video.currentTime >= endTime) {
           video.pause();
        } else {
           /* call checkTime every 1/10th 
              second until endTime */
           setTimeout(checkTime, 100);
        }
    }

    video.currentTime = startTime;
    video.play();
    checkTime();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Let's look at how you might implement this for your app.

You have two 'jump' buttons and a play button. When any of these buttons are activated you could call a single function which sets the start time and end time according to the HTML `id` of the clicked button.  Those values could them be passed into something like the function I've already outlined above.

To begin with, assign an event listener to each button...

```
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');

/* add the same event and 
   handler function to each 
   of the three buttons */
var buttons = ['playme','jump','jump2'];

buttons.forEach(function(bn) {
    document.getElementById(bn).addEventListener(
        'click', buttonEvents, !1
    );
});
```

Here each of you three HTML buttons will call a `buttonEvents()` function when clicked.  That function might look something like this...

```
function buttonEvents(e) {
    /* get the id of the clicked button */
    var element_id = e.target.id;
    /* E.G. element_id = 'playme', 'jump', or 'jump2' */

    /* declare variables before setting them */
    var timeStart = 0;
    var timeEnd = 0;

    /* set start and end values depending 
       on which button was clicked */
    switch(element_id) {
        case 'playme':
            /* example values... */
            timeStart = 0;
            timeEnd = 100; 
            break;
        case 'jump':
            timeStart = 4;
            timeEnd = 12;
            break;
        case 'jump2':
            timeStart = 12;
            timeEnd = 24;
    }

    /* call 'playVideo()' */
    playVideo(timeStart, timeEnd);
}
```

Combining your 'playbutton' function with the general function outlined above would give us something like this: a function that receives a start and end time as it's arguments and plays the video if it's paused or jumps to a new start time if it's playing...

```
function playVideo(startTime, endTime) {

    function checkTime() {
        if (myvideo.currentTime >= endTime) {
           myvideo.pause();
        } else {
           /* call checkTime every 1/10th 
              second until endTime */
           setTimeout(checkTime, 100);
        }
    }

    /* stop if playing (otherwise ignored) */
    myvideo.pause();
    /* set video start time */
    myvideo.currentTime = startTime;
    /* play video */
    myvideo.play();
    /* check the current time and 
       pause IF/WHEN endTime is reached */
    checkTime();
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I implement that into my current code? Still learning javascript so need a little help. thanks